# Delete occurences of item from non-linear list

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I am trying to delete all occurrences of an element from a list, from any levels of the list. **I am required to use a map function though**. I am using Common Lisp. For example I'd want to be able to do:

```
(fdelete '(1 2 3 4 (3)) 3) => (1 2 4)
```

What I've tried so far:
This function will do what's needed, sort of. It will replace all occurences of the given element with NIL, so it's not exactly what I want.

```
(defun fdelete (l e)
    (cond
        ((null l) 0)
        ((equal l e) nil)
        ((atom l) l)
        (t (mapcar (lambda(l) (fdelete l e )) l ))
    )
)
```

This will do

```
(fdelete '(1 2 3 4 (3)) 3) => (1 2 NIL 4 (NIL))
```

My second try is with the mapcap function, since this one won't return a list the same size as the input list.
This will do what's needed, but it will 'destroy' my initial list, as in, it will bring all sublists 'to surface'.

```
(defun fdelete (l e)
    (cond
        ((null l) 0)
        ((equal l e) nil)
        ((atom l) (list l))
        (t(mapcan(lambda(x) (fdelete x e ))l ))
    )
)
```

So this indeed does `(fdelete '(1 2 3 4 (3)) 3) => (1 2 4)`
but it will also do it wrong if I for example try this:

```
(fdelete '(1 2 3 (4) (3)) 3)) => (1 2 4)
```

I'd want it to do `(fdelete '(1 2 3 (4) (3)) 3)) => (1 2 (4))`

I hope my question is well formed and detailed enough, and I am providing working examples. Can someone give me a few hints on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `reduce`  considered a "map function"?

Comment: No, the problem states that I have to use either mapcon, mapcan, mapcar or maplist. This is not homework btw, I am just practicing for an upcoming exam.

Comment: it should be `(fdelete '(1 2 3 4 (3)) 3) => (1 2 4 ())` really, because `(fdelete '(3) 3) => ()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mapcan` is the correct choice since you can wrap in `list` to get a value or use `nil` to get item removed. For the list element, if it doesn't already match what to delete, you should check the result of the recursion and wrap it if it's not the empty list.

The solution would look something like:

```lisp
(defun remove-deep (item list)
  (mapcan (lambda (cur)
            (cond ((equal item cur) '()) 
                  ...))
          list))

(remove-deep 3 '(1 nil 2 3 (3) (3 4)))
; ==> (1 nil 2 (4))
```

To apply the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) I have renamed the function since `delete` is the destructive version of `remove`. Also I kept the argument order of the [standard functions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

Comment: `{3 (3)} ==> ()` hence it must be `{3 (1 3 (3))} ==> (1 ())`.

Comment: @WillNess I agree that to eleminate empty lists as well as the `item` is unconventional. Without looking at the spec I would have expected the result of my test to be `(1 nil 2 nil (4))` which is simpler since you just wrap the recursion regardless, however the OP specifies to also omit lists that has become empty like in my test.

Comment: yes, and I think they were wrong there. I go by simple English, and consistency: removing 3 from (1 3) gives us (1), hence from (3) -- (), hence removing 3 from (1 3 (3)) must give us (1 ()).